# React Router v4 nested route to change the entire content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I have been trying to understand how to apply the concept of nested routes to my scope.

I need these routes:

**/projects**

- Title
- List
- **NavLink** to /projects/new

This route will have a list of projects and a button to create a new project.

**/projects/new**

- Form
- **NavLink** to close and go to /projects

When this route is called, will appear a panel above the content, it doesn't change the page projects.

**/projects/:projectId/dashboard**

- Dashboard Title
- List of items

When a project is selected, I need to show its dashboard in a whole new page, different than the /projects

My react route config:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/>
  <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
  <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
  <Redirect to="/home" push />
</Switch>
```

My render inside projects to receive the other route:

```
<section className='content projects'>
  <div>
    <h3>List</h3>
    <ul>{list}</ul>
  </div>

  <Route path='/projects/new' render={
    () => {
      return <div>
        <h3>New Project</h3>
        <form action="#">
          <input type="text" placeholder='Contract name'/>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Project name'/>
          <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </form>
        <NavLink to='/projects'>Close</NavLink>
      </div>
    }
  } />
</section>
```

Now, where should I put this route:

```
<Route path='/projects/:projectId/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
```

I thought if I put inside the switch, would work, but the page gets blank.

Anyone can help me with this? =)

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to put my dashboard route above /projects with exact. 
Now I'm getting a blank content where it should appear the Dashboard component. The route for projects is still working normally.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route exact path='/projects/:projectId/dashboard' render={ () => {
      return <h2>Dashboard</h2>
  }} />
  <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
  <Redirect to="/home" push />
</Switch>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have created a separated project and **it worked** with the answer in this topic. Now I will try to figure out why it didn't work in the project that I'm having blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `exact` prop to the Route and make sure that it appears BEFORE `/projects` in the `Switch`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/>
  <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
  <Route exact path='/projects/:projectId/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
  <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
  <Redirect to="/home" push />
</Switch>
```

What's happening is your first `/projects` is matching any route that starts with `/projects`. Adding the `exact` prop will make sure that if the route matches `/projects/:projectId/dashboard` exactly, it will render `Dashboard`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I tried what you said but now I'm getting a blank content when it tries the dashboard route. Do you know why? I have updated the question above with an update. Thanks again.